# How can I handle video from the image picker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to cancel while compressing the video.

Currently, it is not possible to cancel during video compression.

If you know how to operate the 'choose' and 'cancel' buttons, please let me know.

[image]

```c
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [UIImagePickerController new];[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie,  (NSString*)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo,  (NSString*)kUTTypeMPEG4];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: after choosing   main thread block is'nt it?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Is there a way to check it?

Comment: as fo as i know i have not seen any way but still can try in completion handler 
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:true completion:nil];
try to unhide navigation bar of imagePickerController so that you can see a cancel button there.

Comment: [self presentViewController: imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        imagePicker.topViewController.title = @"Add";
        imagePicker.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
        imagePicker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        [imagePicker setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];